# Return values on the fly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page there contain a form. At that page I want to get a result after submit.

For that I have added this code to get the data returned in a div:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#ff').form({
            success:function(data){
                $("#hest").show();
                //$.messager.alert('Info', data, 'info');
                $("#message").html(data); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form submit to this php file:

```
<?PHP$x=0;
   while($x<=100)
     {
         echo "The number is: $x \n";
         $x++;
         sleep(1);
     } 
?>
```

When I submit I get the result for all 100 run of the loop, is it possible to get the result for one run of the loop, to see the progress instead of wating for all 100 runs of the loop are finish?

Comment: Not with AJAX, no. Perhaps someone got a better approach, but the first thing I can think of is either an eventstream or websockets, both aren't supported extraordinarily well. +1, though.

Comment: I guess that you want to make a progress bar. You could perform an AJAX request once in every iteration. But things will get unnecessarily complicated .

Comment: Yes, want to have a progress bar or a textarea where it is possible to see the progress of the php script (should call a SMS gateway).

Answer (score 0):

You could call every iteration manually instead of a loop on the server side. But i'm not sure if you should consider this as a nifty solution. This would move the loop to the client side.

Comment: Hi I think I have found a solution: http://www.hellothupten.com/2011/07/20/progress-bar-to-display-servers-script-execution-using-jqueryjqueryui/ it works great.

Comment: Interesting concept. This would work. But be careful. Every client needs its own status.json otherwhise everyone would share the same.